# Viewing Swift optional values in debugger

Tags: debugging, swift

Trying to get my feet wet in writing and debugging Swift code, I wrote the following. This is on OS X 10.10.2, Xcode 6.2.

```
let text : String? = "This is some text.\nJust for fun."

let lines : [String]? =
    text?.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
        NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())

println("\(lines)")
```

Breaking on the `println ...` line, the debugger's variable view shows `Some` as the value of `lines`. In my understanding, this indicates that `lines` is of an optional type and contains a value wrapped in `Some`, as opposed to being `None`.

Knowing that, how can I use the debugger to inspect what that value actually is? I tried:

- clicking the small "i" button, which produces the output "Some" in the debugger console.
- entering `po lines` and `po lines!` in the debugger console, which yields `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. **Update:** Following a fresh installation of Xcode, `po lines` seems to have no effect, i.e. no output.

The final line prints `Optional(["This is some text.", "Just for fun."])`, which is exactly what I'd like the debugger to show.

How can I get at the unwrapped string array value of `lines`, and what is the difference between the optional variable `lines`, whose unwrapped value the debugger doesn't show, and the optional variable `text`, whose value it does show? Will I actually have to introduce an auxiliary variable every time I want to debug an optional value, or use printf-debugging?

Comment: This works just fine for me on Xcode 6.2, both the variable view and the `po`. This is for an OS X app? If you have a breakpoint set to get to the debugger, which line are you breaking on?

Comment: @gregheo Yes, this is a Cocoa application. The breakpoint is on the *println ...* line. What does `po` show on your machine?

Comment: Could it be some lazy evaluation feature of Swift? I just tried stepping over the println statement, and suddenly the value of *lines* showed up as *lines = 2 values*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but you made "lines" an optional value. Because of that, you would need to unwrap it in your println statement or not make it an optional value. Take off the "?" after your "lines" declaration first and see if that works for you.

```
let lines : [String] =
```

Comment: The result of *componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet* is an optional. I could unwrap it afterwards of course, but my question is if I can get at the unwrapped value *in the debugger*. The println statement works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To print an optional value use:

```
if let unwrappedLines = lines { // only executes if lines is not nil
    println("\(unwrappedLines)") // prints the unwrapped variable
}
```